# Jquery undefined function stopping other actions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does an undefined function stop the other actions?

```
  var element=$(".case");
  element.animate({height:"1000px"},200,function(){
   element.removeAttr("style");
   callback();
  });
```

Since `callback()` is an undefined function, `element.removeAttr("style")` won't work. Why does this happen? Just curious.

Otherwise I will use

```
if($.isFunction(callback)){
 callback();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xpdtL0yr/

Comment: just first read javascript documentation first why doesn't work if there is undefined

Comment: What other actions you are talking about here? There is nothing to be done once you invoke `callback()`. Also it is an error and hence execution will stop..

Comment: How a script can execute a line when something is undefined. The parser will check for the function definition and if nothing is found then it halts the execution. You may use mozila fire-bug to detect the **undefined function exception** thrown

Comment: You wrote: element.removeAttr("style") won't work. But it works. at least for me in Firefox. check this:https://jsfiddle.net/xpdtL0yr/1/

Comment: where's `callback()` defined? Should it be passed into the function that is the final param for animate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you are correct, you have to check the function before you call to the callback,
You should check that the name exists, and then check that it's a function, like this:

```
if(typeof  callback !== 'undefined' && $.isFunction(callback)){
         callback();
        }
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LguxrmLL/)

Comment: Why do I need to check if the name exists?

Comment: Its common to check before calling a function its defined or not, otherwise you next part of code ll not work, Its a usual condition to run a code without any interpret.